# How to mock the Kubernetes cluster/server?

Tags: kubernetes, mocking

Kubernetes OpenAPI specification is hosted here.

```
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/api/openapi-spec
```

Additionally, various client APIs for the Kubernetes is provided here:

```
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/
```

Using the OpenAPI specification, I am able to generate the server code, which provides the REST services. However, the applications using these K8s client APIs (written in either language - Go, Java, etc.) do not use these REST API directly.

My objective is to mock the K8s server to use in the test automation and build a controlled environment to create various test scenarios.

Is there any ready-to-use Kubernetes mock available? If not, how we can interface the client APIs with the above OpenAPI generated REST server? This way, the applications shall continue to use the client APIs but internally, they will be communicating with the mocked K8s server and not the real one.

Please help with the options.

.

Comment: Did you consider to use `Microk8s` or Prism https://stoplight.io/open-source/prism/ ?

Comment: Prism is an HTTP mock server and I have used WireMock as well. My problem is not to simulate the K8s REST APIs, but how to connect the K8s client API to this mock REST APIs to build a configurable and controlled K8s cluster for testing of K8s apps.

Answer (score 2):

Not really a direct answer to your question, but most solutions i have seen implemented are not trying to mock the k8s API but are really using it through either k3s (from rancher labs) or KinD project (official way)

You then connect to it like a normal kubernetes cluster

Comment: actualy KinD  is also how kubernetes project itself is launching end to end tests

Comment: The issue is not in using real K8s or their varients. The challenge is how to make a real one behave bad i.e. do some -ve testing. Mocking APIs is one way.